# Writing long string to stdout in nodejs results in partial writes

Tags: node.js, string, stdout

When writing a string to stdout on node js, if the string is really long, it is only partially written. I understand this is because of buffering in the `stream.write` method. In order to solve this problem I write the string a few chars at a time, but I've found this not to be 100% reliable. Sometimes I'll get partial writes with no error printed to screen.

At first I tried calling `process.stdout.once('drain', cb)` when the `write` method returned false, but that didn't seem to work all the time. However, it did lower the rate of unsuccessful writes.

At some point, after over an hour fighting this, I discovered that if I remove the `process.exit(0)` call at the end of my script, there would be no failures, or at least I saw none doing a few tests, whereas I would see errors in less than 5 tries if I left the `process.exit` call.

Here is what I do:

```
const b = JSON.stringify(response.data);
const chunk = 200;
const len = b.length;
let pos;

for (pos = 0; pos <= len; pos += chunk) {
  process.stdout.write(b.substring(pos, pos + chunk));
}

console.log('B'); // This is just a test print out.

// process.exit(0);
```

In the instances where the write would fail, the last 'B' is not printed, which leads me to think that the process just ends without even reaching that line, or without the stream having a chance to write it. I believe it is the second because if I change the exit code to something else, and then run `echo $?` I see that exit code. So `process.exit` is evaluated.

I have a working solution, which is leaving the `process.exit` commented out, but I want to know what the correct way of doing this is. I feel my solution is not the most optimal one.

Also, because I want to explicitly end the process, I've added the next couple lines after the test print out line:

```
process.stdout.on('finish', () => {process.exit(0)});
process.stdout.end();
```

Notes:

1. My code runs inside a promise handler for an axios request.
2. The test string I'm trying to write is 224364 chars long.